# How to add union all in raw query Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony4

I need to use `UNION ALL` in my query. I have stored all my where conditions in a loop.

```
    $lastIndex = count($executionArray) - 1;
    $selectQuery = "";
    foreach ($executionArray as $key => $wheres) {
        $selectQuery .= "SELECT {$selectFields} FROM {$tableName} WHERE ";
        $selectQuery .= $wheres;
        if ($key !== $lastIndex) {
            $selectQuery .= " UNION ALL ";
        }
    }

    $selectStmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($selectQuery);
    $selectStmt->execute($executionArray);
    $return = $selectStmt->fetchAll();
```

I am getting Array to string conversion error. I am not sure where to place `prepare & execute statement`

Can anybody please help me fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: The UNION ALL seems not te be the problem. 
Could you share the content of the $selectQuery

Comment: I have fixed the proble. Its coming from  $selectStmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($selectQuery);
    $selectStmt->execute($executionArray)

Comment: what is your solution?